# How can I active an icon using ID not class and how can I automatically remove and add it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use the ID instead of class because I am using an Icon, I already fixed how I active the icon but not how it will automatically be changed to other icons. I am new to Javascript and I still don't have enough knowledge of how to do it. Please help me, and thank you in advance`

```js
let ul = document.querySelector('ul');
let i = document.querySelectorAll('i');

i.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function (){
        li.querySelector("active").classList.remove('active');
        
        el.classList.add('active');
    });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
:root {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
 
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #23232e;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.25rem;
  
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  
 background: #43434f;
}

main {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 6rem;
  padding: 1rem;
   
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color:  var( --bg-primary);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-align: center;
}


.navbar-nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 65;
  position: relative;
  
  
}

.nav-item a{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #23232e;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10;
  margin: 2px 0;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: -153px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.nav-item a:hover{
 margin-left: 30;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-radius: 20px;
 box-shadow:  15px 5px 5px -5px rgba(0, 3, 7, 0.8);
 
}

ul li i#active {
  filter: grayscale(0) opacity(1);

}

li i{
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.1);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  
}
Li i:hover{
  color: white;
  filter: grayscale(0) opacity(1);
  text-align: right;
  transition: 0.1s ease;
  
}

.logo h1{
 font-family: Rustico;
 font-size: 55px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(7, 57, 255), rgb(255, 10, 10));
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
 text-align: center;
}
.logo h1:hover{
  font-size: 60px;
  transition: 0.60s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
  
}
.logo p{
  color: #ececec;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 55px;
  font-family: APEX;
  text-align: center;
 }

hr{
  filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.1);
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper .icon{
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  
}
.wrapper .icon span{
  color:  #131313;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.1);
}
.wrapper .icon span i{
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper .icon .tooltip{
  position: absolute;
  left: -80px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 25px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  
}
.wrapper .icon:hover .tooltip{
  left: 80px;
  top: 14px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;

  
}

.wrapper .icon:hover span{
  color: #fff;
  filter: opacity(1);
  
}
.wrapper .icon:hover span,
.wrapper .icon:hover .tooltip{
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.wrapper .facebook:hover span,
.wrapper .facebook:hover .tooltip,
.wrapper .facebook:hover .tooltip:before{
  background: #3B5999;
}
.wrapper .twitter:hover span,
.wrapper .twitter:hover .tooltip,
.wrapper .twitter:hover .tooltip:before{
  background: #46C1F6;
}
.wrapper .instagram:hover span,
.wrapper .instagram:hover .tooltip,
.wrapper .instagram:hover .tooltip:before{
  background: #e1306c;
}
.wrapper .github:hover span,
.wrapper .github:hover .tooltip,
.wrapper .github:hover .tooltip:before{
  background: #333;
}
.wrapper .youtube:hover span,
.wrapper .youtube:hover .tooltip,
.wrapper .youtube:hover .tooltip:before{
  background: #DE463B;
}

/* Large screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .navbar {
    top: 0;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 100vh;
  }
 
}
```

```html
<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Style.css"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5a479f40ed.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="JS/Main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar">
  <head>
  <div class="logo">
<h1>AR</h1>
<p>WEBSITE</p>


 </div>
  </head>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">

    <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="">About<i class="far fa-user" id="active"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="">Resume<i class="far fa-file"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="">Portfolio<i class="fas fa-guitar"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="">Contact<i class="far fa-address-card"></i></a>
   
    </li>
```

Comment: The ID should be unique from an element to element. You can append and remove classes from the elements.

Comment: How? My apology I am new to Java script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `setAttribute()` method to assign `id`. And also `removeAttribute()` to remove `id`, respectively.

For your understanding, I will display part of the code that I used in the solution:

```
Array.from(i).forEach(el => el.removeAttribute('id'));
this.setAttribute('id', 'active');
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  let i = document.querySelectorAll('i');

  i.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function (event){
      event.preventDefault();
      Array.from(i).forEach(el => el.removeAttribute('id'));
      this.setAttribute('id', 'active');
    });
  });
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
:root {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
 
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #23232e;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.25rem;
  
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  
 background: #43434f;
}

main {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 6rem;
  padding: 1rem;
   
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color:  var( --bg-primary);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-align: center;
}


.navbar-nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 65;
  position: relative;
  
  
}

.nav-item a{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #23232e;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10;
  margin: 2px 0;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: -153px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.nav-item a:hover{
 margin-left: 30;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-radius: 20px;
 box-shadow:  15px 5px 5px -5px rgba(0, 3, 7, 0.8);
 
}

ul li i#active {
  filter: grayscale(0) opacity(1);

}

li i{
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.1);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  
}
Li i:hover{
  color: white;
  filter: grayscale(0) opacity(1);
  text-align: right;
  transition: 0.1s ease;
  
}

.logo h1{
 font-family: Rustico;
 font-size: 55px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(7, 57, 255), rgb(255, 10, 10));
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
 text-align: center;
}
.logo h1:hover{
  font-size: 60px;
  transition: 0.60s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
  
}
.logo p{
  color: #ececec;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 55px;
  font-family: APEX;
  text-align: center;
 }

hr{
  filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.1);
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper .icon{
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  
}
.wrapper .icon span{
  color:  #131313;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.1);
}
.wrapper .icon span i{
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper .icon .tooltip{
  position: absolute;
  left: -80px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 25px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  
}
.wrapper .icon:hover .tooltip{
  left: 80px;
  top: 14px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;

  
}

.wrapper .icon:hover span{
  color: #fff;
  filter: opacity(1);
  
}
.wrapper .icon:hover span,
.wrapper .icon:hover .tooltip{
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.wrapper .facebook:hover span,
.wrapper .facebook:hover .tooltip,
.wrapper .facebook:hover .tooltip:before{
  background: #3B5999;
}
.wrapper .twitter:hover span,
.wrapper .twitter:hover .tooltip,
.wrapper .twitter:hover .tooltip:before{
  background: #46C1F6;
}
.wrapper .instagram:hover span,
.wrapper .instagram:hover .tooltip,
.wrapper .instagram:hover .tooltip:before{
  background: #e1306c;
}
.wrapper .github:hover span,
.wrapper .github:hover .tooltip,
.wrapper .github:hover .tooltip:before{
  background: #333;
}
.wrapper .youtube:hover span,
.wrapper .youtube:hover .tooltip,
.wrapper .youtube:hover .tooltip:before{
  background: #DE463B;
}

/* Large screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .navbar {
    top: 0;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 100vh;
  }
 
}
```

```html
<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Style.css"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5a479f40ed.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="JS/Main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar">
  <head>
  <div class="logo">
<h1>AR</h1>
<p>WEBSITE</p>


 </div>
  </head>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">

    <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="">About<i class="far fa-user" id="active"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="">Resume<i class="far fa-file"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="">Portfolio<i class="fas fa-guitar"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="">Contact<i class="far fa-address-card"></i></a>
   
    </li>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225982/discussion-on-answer-by-sergey-kuznetsov-how-can-i-active-an-icon-using-id-not-c).

Answer (score 0):

If I quite understood your doubt, then you should only add inside the querySelector method "#". Would be something like:

```
i.forEach(el => {
el.addEventListener('click', function (){
    li.querySelector("#active").classList.removeAttribute('id');
    
    el.id = 'newid';
});
```

});

Comment: You mean something like this? i.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function (){
        li.querySelector("#active").classList.removeAttribute('id');
        
        el.id = 'newid';
    });